# Directly use the MCU chip from some RF LoRa boards

Tags: microcontroller, lora, consumption

While buying some LoRa boards for my battery powered wireless sensors based on atmega328p, I fund a lot of SX1278 boards having an uart communication interface. My first reaction was to avoid those cause I prefer my direct SPI communication with my atme328p controller. I was thinking that an additional MCU in the board was useless and draw more current for nothing.

But then comes an idea: I could choose one of these LoRa boards with MCU integrated and use it as my micontroller by reprogramming it. No more atmega needed, smaller size, already connected to LoRa chip.

Apart from LoRa chip, I found some information on C1101 board witch integrate an STM8 MCU : https://mvdlande.wordpress.com/2016/09/03/reprogramming-a-hc-11-cc1101-433mhz-wireless-transceiver-module/

Does someone had some information to do this on LoRa modules like the E32-433T20 for example ? http://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.aspx?id=660

PS: Sorry for my low english level

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if you can in fact reprogram an integrated LoRaWAN chip solution than yes. You can reprogram the RN2483 and RN2903 because of its integrated PIC microcontroller.

Comment: Hi, I was asking about some boards from ebyte like [this one](http://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.aspx?id=660) which include a SX1278 LoRa chip + a MCU to add the UART interface. But I guess it's the same for the RN2483/RN2903 you talk about? I will look at thoose, thank you